# Add buttons/dropdownlist to sitecore webedit editor?

Tags: sitecore, page-editor

Is it possible to add more buttons or a dropdownlist to the webedit editor when you are viewing the page in the page editor in sitecore?

If you look at the image below I would like to add a "H2" button in the toolbar.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add it to `/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Default/WebEdit Buttons/`.

And, to create a h2-button, enter the following into the Click field of the new item:

```
chrome:field:execute({command:"FormatBlock", userInterface:true, value:'h2'})
```

('h2' being the [block format](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/execCommand.html) you want)

Comment: In Sitecore 6.6 it does work for me in Chrome (except for the fact that it formats whole block of the text instead of selection). I does not work in Firefox 14 neither in IE8.

Comment: I have created a H2 item like you instructed me here. But It dosen't show up in the webedit editor? I've made a full publish too. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: @Maras It will format the whole block och text since we're calling FormatBlock, since <h2> is a block tag.

Comment: @Raskolnikoov Have you changed the HTML Editor Profile for the field? In that case the button needs to be added to that profile as well. Check the template to see that what Editor Profile is used. Also, don't forget to add an icon, not sure if it will show up without an icon.

Comment: @Raskolnikoov which Sitecore version you use?

Comment: @Maras it works in IE, but seems kind of buggy. If I select all the text in the block, it works, but not if I only select a single word. FF _should_ work, but doesn't. SC is calling document.execCommand(command, null, null); which is wrong according to the FF docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla#Executing_Commands)

Comment: @andreasordell It's working now, I was working with the wrong profile. :)

Comment: @andreasordell do you know how to add a class to the html tag? So it would render like <h2 class="myclass">...</h2>

Comment: @Raskolnikoov I don't think that this is possible using the simple edit frame buttons of the Page Editor out of the box, sorry. You could probably build it if needed. Check out EditFrameChromeType.js in sitecore\shell\Applications\Page Modes\ChromeTypes (handleMessage function) for a start.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible.
You need to modify the Html Editor Profile for this which is located in the `Core` database under `/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles`

If you look at the `Full` profile, you can find a command for H2 (and other headings) there somewhere. This can be easily copied to the profile that you are currently using (i guess it's the `Minimal` profile).
If you have access to the web.config, you may want to create a copy of the Minimal profile before editing it and configure it as `HtmlEditor.DefaultProfile`

Comment: it looks like the question is about the buttons in page editor window, not in the RTE which is opened as a modal window. And `Full` profile doesn't provide any additional button for `page editor` rich text.

Comment: Yes that is correct @Maras. I want to add buttons to the editor in page-editor mode.