# Sitecore add css class dropdown to webedit button

Tags: html, sitecore, text-editor, sitecore7

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/78GIX.png]

I need to add a css class selector to the webeditor buttons. I already found the location where I need to do this ( /sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Full/WebEdit Buttons ) but I have no clue what to add to get the Dropdown there.

It's comparable with this question(@Raskolnikoov thx for the image):  [Add buttons/dropdownlist to sitecore webedit editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984568/add-buttons-dropdownlist-to-sitecore-webedit-editor) but I need to add the full dropdownlist just like in the full text editor

Answer (score -1):

You just need to update the template for the item that you are editing. In the source field for the RichTextEditor field, insert the path to the profile you want to use.

from the Client Configuration Cookbook:

> *Developers may reference an RTE profile using the source property of each RTE field definition item. Sitecore stores RTE profiles under
>   /Sitecore/System/Settings/Html Editor Profiles in the Core database.
>   If the developer does not define the source property for an RTE field,
>   Sitecore applies the /Sitecore/System/Settings/Html Editor
>   Profiles/Rich Text Default RTE profile.*